# Session Managment between NodeJS and Angular using JSONWebToken

Tags: node.js, angular, session, express, json-web-token

I'm trying to build an application in such a way that NodeJS serves as the backend with all business logic exposing JSON REST services to be consumed by the angular 4 app which is nothing but a dumb client. So far so good, however I'm having a hard time figuring the Session management.

I found that token based authentication is a way to go since you might one day be serving mobile apps however, I have a problem: if I go with JSONWebToken strategy on the server side with token expiration set to half an hour, then my client will need to re authenticate it self after half an hour which doesn't seem like a good fit, because then it may force the user to sign in again that is already working on the client application which is not how any web app works. Should I also need to maintain session management at Angular level and auto sign in if my token expires on server but then it violates the principle of a dumb client or I should scrap it altogether implement sessions at NodeJS it self? Another thing is if I implement the WebTokenStrategy I found that for every request that comes from the client I'll be making a trip to database to verify a user which I can cache in session if I'm doing session management on NodeJS.

Last thing that I have a hard time figuring out is okay I can secure my resources on NodeJS but then I also need my routes and pages to be served depending on user rights in my client application, should I also store this information in the NodeJS database and serve by the same API server but I think this again violates the single responsibility principle or should there be another database for this client site route and user management.

Can someone suggest a good approach and if possible with examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No a JSON web token do not required a trip to the database since you encode the information you want on the payload. However you can implement a redis strategy if you want to be able to revoke them (For right changes for example). The signature part will be used by your server to ensure the authenticity (thanks to your server-side JWT secret).

You can also choose the expiration time you want. But if you want to limit it to 30 minutes you can also implement a renew strategy. (Ask for a new token before the old one will expire soon : The server will just deliver a new token with the same data encode. For the front end renew strategy you can use such a lib :

```js
'use strict';

/**
 * Helper class to decode and find JWT expiration.
 */
class JwtHelper {

  urlBase64Decode(str) {
    let output = str.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
    switch (output.length % 4) {
      case 0: { break; }
      case 2: { output += '=='; break; }
      case 3: { output += '='; break; }
      default: {
        throw 'Illegal base64url string!';
      }
    }
    return this.b64DecodeUnicode(output);
  }

  // credits for decoder goes to https://github.com/atk
  b64decode(str) {
    let chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';
    let output = '';

    str = String(str).replace(/=+$/, '');

    if (str.length % 4 == 1) {
      throw new Error("'atob' failed: The string to be decoded is not correctly encoded.");
    }

    for (
      // initialize result and counters
      let bc = 0, bs, buffer, idx = 0;
      // get next character
      buffer = str.charAt(idx++);
      // character found in table? initialize bit storage and add its ascii value;
      ~buffer && (bs = bc % 4 ? bs * 64 + buffer : buffer,
        // and if not first of each 4 characters,
        // convert the first 8 bits to one ascii character
        bc++ % 4) ? output += String.fromCharCode(255 & bs >> (-2 * bc & 6)) : 0
    ) {
      // try to find character in table (0-63, not found => -1)
      buffer = chars.indexOf(buffer);
    }
    return output;
  }

  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#The_Unicode_Problem
  b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(Array.prototype.map.call(this.b64decode(str), (c) => {
      return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
  }

  decodeToken(token) {
    let parts = token.split('.');

    if (parts.length !== 3) {
      throw new Error('JWT must have 3 parts');
    }

    let decoded = this.urlBase64Decode(parts[1]);
    if (!decoded) {
      throw new Error('Cannot decode the token');
    }

    return JSON.parse(decoded);
  }

  getTokenExpirationDate(token) {
    let decoded;
    decoded = this.decodeToken(token);

    if (!decoded.hasOwnProperty('exp')) {
      return null;
    }

    let date = new Date(0); // The 0 here is the key, which sets the date to the epoch
    date.setUTCSeconds(decoded.exp);

    return date;
  }

  isTokenExpired(token, offsetSeconds) {
    let date = this.getTokenExpirationDate(token);
    offsetSeconds = offsetSeconds || 0;

    if (date == null) {
      return false;
    }

    // Token expired?
    return !(date.valueOf() > (new Date().valueOf() + (offsetSeconds * 1000)));
  }
}

const jwtHelper =  new JwtHelper();

const decodedData = jwtHelper.decodeToken('eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ');

console.log(decodedData)
```

Comment: So, in essence I do need a session management mechanism at client side which caches the username and password and re invokes the token once it found it to be expired on the server side? Or should I encode the username and password in the payload it self as it will prevent the caching of username/password on the client site? Having said all that, should I also encode all session info like ACL etc into the payload it self, in order to avoid a trip to DB?

Comment: No, ask a new token BEFORE the token is expired ` isTokenExpired(token, offsetSeconds)`. Do not store credentials in the token : it makes no sense and everyone is able to decode a token so it will be a huge security issue. Also you can store permissions in the token : 
See : https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt-permissions

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I'm still a bit confused. Sorry for the trouble. I understand that I need to resissue the token before it expires, however from the client site purpose, I'm maintaining a session on the client side and asking for the token before it expires. Also can you renew a token without generating a new one from user credentials? Secondly, it's not directly related to the token management but can I also store the pages or routes information of the client side in the token not the REST resources of the server or would that violate the principle of atomicity?